# High draw count results in low FPS on iOS device unity

Tags: c#, ios, performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I have a relatively simple game, however when I run it on iOS the fps is very low as my draw count is too high. However I am not sure if I can use static batching in this case as almost all my graphics are moving around in the scene at different speeds. Any suggestions to help increase the fps would be appreciated...

EDIT 1:
My game is 2d

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Adding instancing to your Materials

To enable GPU Instancing on Materials, select your Material in the Project window, and in the Inspector, tick the Enable Instancing checkbox.

[image]
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html

2) Quality Settings 
Unity allows you to set the level of graphical quality it will attempt to render. Generally speaking, quality comes at the expense of framerate and so it may be best not to aim for the highest quality on mobile devices or older hardware since it will have a detrimental effect on gameplay. The Quality Settings inspector (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Quality) is used to select the quality level in the editor for the chosen device. It is split into two main areas - at the top, there is the following matrix:
[image]
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html

Hope this thing will help on your project...

Comment: Hi, thanks for a lot for your answer as it has showed me in the right direction. However, my fps is still very low and I am pretty clueless on what i could still possibly optimize